# CefSharp FileSystem API - Delete Files On Startup

Tags: html5-filesystem, cefsharp

I have a wonderfully fringe problem that I hope someone might be able to shed some light on.

In a nutshell, we host a Durandal driven SPA inside a CefSharp powered Windows application. This application runs full screen and for all intents and purposes acts like a native application. This application is intended to be running for days and to aid in debugging issues I have been working with the FileSystem API to log web events to a physical file.

This works beautifully, and all logs get written to the "expected" random file name you get when testing this in Google Chrome. "~CachePath\File System\000\t\00\000000000"

However, when a new instance of CefSharp is loaded up, or the current one closed and re-opened, the 00\0000000 folder\file gets deleted. I obviously don't want it to do this.

I not exactly sure which version of CefSharp we are using (as I didn't write the original windows application), but I know we are not using CefSharp 3 yet.

Any insight into this matter would be gratefully received. Thanks!

EDIT--

I have discovered through further testing, that the aforementioned folder only gets deleted if a new instance of the CefSharp browser is created while one is already open. And only seems to be when the browser is hosting a site that is accessing some sort of cache

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `--cache-path` on the command line (or programatically via `CefSettings.CachePath` as [this CefSharp search](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/search?q=CachePath&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93) gives a glimpse into).

See more in the wonderful CEF documentation: http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/(default)/_cef_settings_t.html#cache_path

Comment: Thanks for the reply..

I am currently setting the CachePath. Inside the CachePath there are directories for local storage and application cache which don't get deleted. it seems to only be this one folder deep within the file system directory. I have actually discovered more info about the issue and have edited my question above